# Find XML Values based on regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a recipe XML FIle that has values that are wildcarded (based on the * symbol). I have code that is supposed to determine values that match but it is not finding any results.

I have been reading all about LINQ and regex and following [this](http://technico.qnownow.com/perform-wild-card-search-using-xml-linq/)

What am i doing wrong ?

**C# Code**

```
 Regex regEx = new Regex("450455-501", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            XDocument recipefile = XDocument.Load(@"C:\testData\Recipes\Recipes.xml");

            var recipes = (from recipe in recipefile.Descendants("recipe").
               Where(r => regEx.IsMatch(r.Element("partnumber").Value))
                           select new
                           {
                               partnumber = recipe.Element("partnumber").Value,
                               recipename = recipe.Element("recipename ").Value,
                           });

            //print product attributes to the console
            foreach (var recipe in recipes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Product Name:    " + recipe.partnumber);
                MessageBox.Show("List Price:      " + recipe.recipename);
            }
```

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
    <recipes>
    <recipe>
        <partnumber value="450455-50*" />
        <recipename value="porkchop" />
    </recipe>
    <recipe>
        <partnumber value="420100-1**" />
        <recipename value="porkchop" />
    </recipe>
    </recipes>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the given xml?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is expecting the regex `/450455-501/` to match `420100-1**`, which makes no sense and shows no sign of your having tried to find out what regexes are.

Comment: Actually, what you're doing wrong is trusting that the author of [this pseudo-article](http://technico.qnownow.com/perform-wild-card-search-using-xml-linq/) knows anything more about the subject than you do. That article is worthless, unfortunately. The critical point is the content of the regular expression itself, which is never mentioned in the article.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok - so bad article - I still dont know what to do - ive looked up regex but its not that clear - If its just the regex is wrong ok - but my worry is that my code is broken in multiple places - if thats not the case then ok

Comment: @user1438082 If you have found one bug in your code (here's one: That regex string is wrong), fix it. Don't worry about other bugs. Fix the one you have. Use the debugger to make sure that that one thing is working. If the code then breaks somewhere else, *then* worry about that bug.

Comment: Regular expressions are a language unto themselves, and will take some work. I would suggest writing test code to play with the regex you're trying to write in isolation, rather than testing it with unproven linq-to-xml code. Isolate the one problem you have, don't mix that in with other, totally unproven code. You have to break large, complcated problems down into simpler, more manageable ones, and resolve them one at a time.

Comment: There are couple (I mean [couple hundred thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)) questions about all sorts of regex on SO alone. It is very surprising you can't find plausible match to "numbers and some other symbols" regex... Coming up with [MCVE] (instead of I copy-pasted some random code fix it for me) would make post more appropriate for SO than post in current state.

Comment: You should also re-examine your theory that `XElement.Value` returns the value of attributes named `value`.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
// Load the recipe
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test\Recipes\Recipes.xml");
            string response = "420100-199";

            //Note If you know the result should contain 0 or 1 elements, you can use FirstOrDefault() instead of ToList();
            var results = (from c in doc.Descendants("recipe")
                           from f in c.Descendants("partnumber")
                           where Regex.IsMatch(response ,WildcardToRegex((string)f.Attribute("value")))
                           select c).ToList();


            if (results.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Recipe Found  ");
                return;
            }

            else if(results.Count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: More than 1 recipe matches the part number");

            }

            else
            {
                textBox_recipe.Text = string.Format("{0}", results[0].Element("recipename").Attribute("value").Value);
            }
```

// Method to convert wildcarded part numbers using * symbol into compatible regular expressions

```
public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{
    return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern)
                      .Replace(@"\*", ".*")
                      .Replace(@"\?", ".")
               + "$";
}
```

Comment: What is `WildCardToRegex`? If you don't include the code for that function, this isn't an answer to the question.